# Detecting even and odd C++ vector iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I searched and I'm surprised this hasn't been asked yet. I know how to do it with a simple loop, how about with vector iterators?

```
for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = somevector.begin(); it != somevector.end(); ++it )
{
    //Conditions stating a certain vector has an even or odd index.
}
```

Sorry for not clarifying, I meant detecting whether the index of a vector is odd or even.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking. Are you asking if the vector has even or odd elements? Or if the elements are odd or even?

Comment: You mean an element IN the vector is odd, or that the vector itself has an odd number of elements, or?

Comment: what does an "odd" vector mean ? containing only odd elements ? In what does it differ from using a simple loop instead of iterators ?

Comment: Your question is odd.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Did you even read it?

Comment: You say that you know how to do "it" in a loop. Could you provide the code of said loop, such that we can understand exactly what behavior you want to translated over to iterators?

Comment: @Pubby That doesn't make a good joke now does it (also yes, it's bad)

Comment: Are you trying to find odd number in vector?

Comment: Updated the description, sorry guys. I thought the title was enough considering I said "detecting even or odd (vector) iterators" which means I was talking about the index.

Comment: Can you guys rectify the down votes now that the question is very clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess you meant you wanted to detect if the current index is even or odd:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> somevector;
    somevector.push_back(1);
    somevector.push_back(2);
    somevector.push_back(4);
    somevector.push_back(8);
    somevector.push_back(111605);

    for (auto it = somevector.begin(); it != somevector.end(); ++it)
    {
        // current index
        const auto index = std::distance(somevector.begin(), it);

        if ((index % 2) == 0) // even
        {
            std::cout << "Index " << index << " (even) is: " << *it;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Index " << index << " (odd) is: " << *it;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can get the distance between iterators with `std::distance`. (Index being distance from the start.)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This would be one simple way:

```
{
  bool is_even = true;
  for (const auto& v: somevector) {
    if (is_even) even_handler(v);
    else         odd_handler(v);
    is_even = !is_even;
  }
}
```

---

Want a more complicated solution? No problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using std::next;
template<typename Iter, typename Func, typename...Funcs>
void RotateHandlers(Iter b, Iter e, Func f, Funcs...fs) {
    if (b != e) {
        f(*b);
        RotateHandlers(next(b), e, fs..., f);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v({"Hello", "world", "it's", "really", "great", "to", "be", "here"});
    RotateHandlers(v.begin(), v.end(),
      [](const std::string& s){std::cout << "First|" << s << std::endl;},
      [](const std::string& s){std::cout << "Then |" << s << std::endl;},
      [](const std::string& s){std::cout << "And  |" << s << std::endl
                                         << "     |" << std::string(s.size(), '-') << std::endl;}
    );
    return 0;
}
```

See it here: http://ideone.com/jmlV5F

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question [before its last edit] correctly, an option is:

```
bool is_odd(const std::vector<int> &somevector) {
    for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = somevector.begin(); it != somevector.end(); ++it ) {
        //Conditions stating a certain vector is even or odd.
        if (*it % 2 == 0) {
          return false; 
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

respectively for "even vectors".

Comment: please consider commenting the answer instead of downvoting. This does answer the question, as it can be understood (detect if all elements are odd : if there is one even, return false).

Comment: The downvotes are probably for the flags. Just return a bool and call it `is_even`.